# new line while concatenation of string in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular2 in which i need to create a new line for my dynamically created string.

eg.

input:

Hello how are you ?

output:

Hello

how

are

you?

Here is my code:

.html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="well">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Import Data</h1>
                    <p class="text-center">{{selectedLogContent.message}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is the typescript code:

```
var splitString = selectedRows[0].description.split(":");
            var messageString= splitString[3].split(".");
            var messageStringAfter ="";
            for(var i=0;i<messageString.length;i++){
                messageStringAfter= messageStringAfter+`\ 
                \n`+messageString[i];
            }
            var finalString = splitString[0]+":"+splitString[1]+":"+splitString[2]+': '+messageStringAfter;
            console.log(finalString);
            this.selectedLogContent.message = finalString;
```

I tried using '\n' while concatenation of the string still ending up the output in the same line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Because the tag `angular2`, I would try: `Hello<br>how<br>are<br>you?` ;)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: i tried using the <br> but getting the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing big with angular2 to do here all you need is a *ngFor to achieve as below,

```
<div *ngFor="let s of values.split(' ')">
      {{s}} <br/>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1qlgChZkDMOSUmxBrfw?p=preview)**

Comment: happy helping you :)

Comment: nice and compact.